# Anchor jump animation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So another question regarding my website: I'm trying to animate the "anchor jump" using JQuery and I'm using the following code. As it seems to me, this should work, but it doesn't quite.

Forgot to mention: Whenever any of the buttons in the header is pressed, the anchor jump should be performed.

```js
$(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        if (this.hash) {
            var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

            var $scrollToElement = $("a[name=" + hash + "]");
            var scrollToPosition = $scrollToElement.position().top;

            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: scrollToPosition
            }, 1000, "swing");

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div name="home" id="body_container">
    <div id="banner_container">
        <img id="banner" />
    </div>
    <div id="content_container">
        <div name="over" id="over_content"></div>
        <div name="contact" id="contact_content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see all the code in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jksups47/)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jksups47/1/).

Comment: @Harry Kind of, yeah! But any idea why the second button scrolls the page back to the top? If you can explain it and post it in an answer my problem is solved!

Comment: That is because, the `position().top` doesn't seem to be returning a proper value possibly due to your `fixed` position elements. I will find that out and post an answer (or if you wish to, I will post an answer now and update that part later).

Comment: @Harry No hurries, I'd rather have a complete answer ;) Thanks for you hard work!

Comment: I have added an answer just to explain the other parts. I don't mind you accepting the other answer because that solved both your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Harry's solution, you should change

`var scrollToPosition = $scrollToElement.position().top;`

to

`var scrollToPosition = $scrollToElement.offset().top;`

position() gives you the relative offset to the container (which is 0 in your case), and offset will give you the offset to you whole document, and that helps you scroll correctly.

try this http://jsfiddle.net/eax7ppwb/2/

Comment: maybe `var scrollToPosition = $scrollToElement.offset().top - $('header').height();` will be a better idea.

Comment: (Your fiddle doesn't seem to be updated to me, at least it doesn't work right now.) Nvm you made an edit

Comment: Ah, you have now put me in a dilemma mate. I just found out and was updating pretty much the same. Maybe since you have already posted, I will post the other part of the answer and give you the credit for this :) +1.

Comment: @Harry sorry about that :( I saw you just commented 20 mins ago when I posted, didn't know you're working on this.

Comment: Thanks that works. Now, off-topic, what would be the best way to change the classes of the menu items (so that the one you click on becomes selected)? I feel like there is a real easy jQuery solution, but I already know it's going to be a lot of lines in Javascript.

Comment: @lozy219: No worries mate. You were the first to fix the problem fully :)

Comment: @YSbakker http://jsfiddle.net/eax7ppwb/4/ the 'selected' class is added to the <a>, you need to set the style for the menuItem class actually.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems in your code all of which together is resulting in the code not working as you expect. They are as follows:

- `this.hash` refers to the target that is part of the URL.For this to return a value, your anchor tag's `href` should be set. (For example, like `<a href ='#over'`)
- Whenever any of the link is clicked, the page has to animate to the part of the page where the corresponding content is present. For this, you should target the `div` with the required name and not the `a` tag. If you get the `top` of the `a` tag and try to animate to it there would be no movement because that is the same tag which you had clicked.

Below snippet has both the issues addressed and would work as per your expectation: (**Note:** The snippet has the position issue also fixed thanks to [**lozy219**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3747600/lozy219)'s answer.)

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    if (this.hash) {
      var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

      var $scrollToElement = $("div[name=" + hash + "]");
      var headerHeight = $('header').height();
      var scrollToPosition = $scrollToElement.offset().top - headerHeight;

      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: scrollToPosition
      }, 1000, "swing");

      /* To add/remove class */
      $('.menuItem').removeClass('selected'); // first remove class from all menu items
      $(this).children('.menuItem').addClass('selected'); // then add to the clicked item
      
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  background: rgb(223, 227, 238);
  text-align: center;
}
header {
  min-width: 100%;
  background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}
#header_container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 100%;
}
#header_container div {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
#logo {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
.menuItem {
  padding-top: 29px;
  height: calc(100% - 29px);
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Signika;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgb(203, 207, 218);
}
.menuItem:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(59, 89, 202);
  height: calc(100% - 33px);
  color: rgb(160, 170, 218);
}
.selected {
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(59, 89, 202);
  height: calc(100% - 33px);
  color: rgb(160, 170, 218);
}
.menuLogo {
  padding-top: 14.5px;
  height: calc(100% - 14.5px);
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#mobile_menu_button {
  display: none;
}
#body_container {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
#banner_container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#banner {
  width: 1024px;
  height: auto;
}
#content_container {
  background: rgb(235, 235, 240);
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(235, 235, 240);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(235, 235, 240);
}
#over_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}
#contact_content {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="header_container">
    <div class="menuLogo">
      <img id="logo" />
    </div>
    <a href="#home">
      <div id="homeButton" class="menuItem selected">Home</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#over">
      <div id="overButton" class="menuItem">Over</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#contact">
      <div id="contactButton" class="menuItem">Contact</div>
    </a>

    <div id="mobile_menu_button"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div name="home" id="body_container">
  <div id="banner_container">
    <img id="banner" />
  </div>
  <div id="content_container">
    <div name="over" id="over_content">Over menu's content</div>
    <div name="contact" id="contact_content">Contact menu's content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @YSbakker: The updated snippet does the add/remove classes as required.